# How do I get to tap on a CustomPaint path in Flutter using GestureDetect?

Tags: flutter, dart, path, gesturedetector, custom-painting

I'm very new to flutter and am trying to figure out how to get a gesture detected on a CustomPaint path. I can click on a host of other things but not on paths for some reason... How do I get this to work? My code thus far is below.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MbiraShapes());

class MbiraShapes extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
  _MbiraShapesState createState() => _MbiraShapesState();
}

class _MbiraShapesState extends State<MbiraShapes>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Mbira Shapes',
        home: PathExample());
  }
}

class PathExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: KeyPathPainter(),
    );
  }
}

class KeyPathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint lineDrawer = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    Path path = Path()
// Moves to starting point
      ..moveTo(50, 50)
      //draw lines passing through xc, yc to end at x,y
      ..quadraticBezierTo(77, 370, 50, 750)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(100, 775, 150, 750)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(110, 440, 75, 50);
    //close shape from last point
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, lineDrawer);

    Path path2 = Path()
// Moves to starting point
      ..moveTo(250, 50)
      //draw lines passing through xc, yc to end at x,y
      ..quadraticBezierTo(280, 350, 270, 675)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(290, 750, 350, 750)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(365, 710, 345, 600)
      ..quadraticBezierTo(320, 450, 270, 50);
    //close shape from last point
    path2.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path2, lineDrawer);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

I tried the snippet below with GestureDetector but it does not work.
I tried a Listener but get no response for onPointerDown, only for onPointerMove, but I need a tap action, not a move action.

```html
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
  
        title: Text("widget.title)"),
      ),
      
      body: Center(
        child: GestureDetector(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: KeyPathPainter(),
            child: Container()),
          onTap: () {
            print("tapped the key");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I just want to tap a key and get a response, it will be a sound in the end but for now, I'm just trying to figure out how to get the onTap to work.

Comment: I made a library for this purpose :  https://pub.dev/packages/touchable   which lets you add gesture callbacks to each individual objects you draw on canvas.

Answer (score 14):

You have to override the `hitTest()` method of your `KeyPathPainter` class:

```
@override
bool hitTest(Offset position) {
    // _path - is the same one we built in paint() method;
    return _path.contains(position);
}
```

That will allow `GestureDetector` to detect taps inside the path instead of the entire `CustomPaint` container. Though the `_path` must be closed since there's no way—at least that I know of—to test hits on curves.

Answer (score 3):

I came to this from googling an issue I had. My issue was I was just wrapping the Painter in a gesture detector like:

```
GestureDetector(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: CustomPainter(),
      ),

      onTapDown: _handleTapDown,
);
```

Where the solution was I needed to have a `Container` with a color, wrapping the Custom Painter, like so:

```
return GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: CustomPaint(
          painter: CustomPainter(),
        ),
      ),

      onTapDown: _handleTapDown,
);
```

Comment: Same, you may also pass an empty Container to the child property of CustomPaint

Answer (score 2):

You should have a child of CustomPaint

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return CustomPaint(
       painter: YourAwesomePainter(),
       child: Container(), // this line will solve the tap problem
    );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your paint with a gesture detector should do the work.

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (details) {
         print("${details.globalPosition.dx}");
         print("${details.globalPosition.dy}");
     },
  ),
```

Comment: Hi sorry I don't understand I thought that was what I had already done with the second snippet above, having the child KeyPainter inside CustomPaint and inside GestureDetector.. that does not work... Please explain to me where I am getting it wrong

Comment: I'm testing your code and it works, it detects the gesture

Answer (score 0):

Use LeafRenderObjectWidget instead of CustomPaint.

1. LeafRenderObjectWidget override createRenderObject method.
2. createRenderObject return RenderConstrainedBox.
3. RenderConstrainedBox override handlerEvent/hitTestSelf/paint method.

You can implement your gesture recognizer in `handleEvent(PointerEvent event, BoxHitTestEntry entry)` method.

or

Extends your gesture recognizer base on system classes `VerticalDragGestureRecognizer/HorizontalDragGestureRecognizer/PanGestureRecognizer/...`

Answer (score -1):

You need to put `GestureDetector` as a child of `CustomPainter`. In your case :

```dart
class PathExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: KeyPathPainter(),
      // Add 5 following lines
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          // Handle your tap here
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```