# child customPaint can't click

Tags: flutter, click, custom-painting

```
  GestureDetector(
   // behavior:HitTestBehavior(),
    onTap: (){
      print('hello word');
      //print(gl);
     // print(value.localPosition.dx);
    },
    child:
     CustomPaint(
       size: Size(setRawSize(600), setRawSize(290)),
       foregroundPainter: FunnelPlotCustomPainter(
         viewService.context,
         color: Colors.blue,
         funnelPoltData: fd
        ),
     ),
  ),
```

i use canvas to draw a funnel dirgram,but i can't click it.i am confused.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot click it? What did you do? What did you expect to happen? What happened instead?

Comment: Is `hitTest` being called in your `CustomPaint` like this answer is suggesting? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61928397/6704033