# How can I change color with GestureDetector of svg image and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, canvas, flutter-custompainter

I need your help, I'am developing an app where the user will select any SVG image previously converted with flutterShapeMaker to get and set several classes as you see below (fragment example, I have 20 classes)

```
class PathUno extends CustomPainter{
  final Color color;
  PathUno(this.color);
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path_1 = Path();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.7138889,size.height*0.3569444);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7259804,size.height*0.3599747,size.width*0.7367647,size.height*0.3650253,size.width*0.7468954,size.height*0.3705808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7586601,size.height*0.3771465,size.width*0.7694444,size.height*0.3844697,size.width*0.7761438,size.height*0.3949495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7823529,size.height*0.4047980,size.width*0.7794118,size.height*0.4148990,size.width*0.7638889,size.height*0.4190657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7485294,size.height*0.4231061,size.width*0.7339869,size.height*0.4217172,size.width*0.7187908,size.height*0.4193182);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7040850,size.height*0.4169192,size.width*0.6892157,size.height*0.4148990,size.width*0.6750000,size.height*0.4111111);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6684641,size.height*0.4093434,size.width*0.6620915,size.height*0.4073232,size.width*0.6552288,size.height*0.4061869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6517974,size.height*0.4055556,size.width*0.6500000,size.height*0.4053030,size.width*0.6517974,size.height*0.4088384);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6647059,size.height*0.4327020,size.width*0.6648693,size.height*0.4574495,size.width*0.6612745,size.height*0.4825758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6583333,size.height*0.5037879,size.width*0.6514706,size.height*0.5243687,size.width*0.6449346,size.height*0.5450758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6436275,size.height*0.5491162,size.width*0.6431373,size.height*0.5532828,size.width*0.6421569,size.height*0.5574495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6415033,size.height*0.5599747,size.width*0.6424837,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.6457516,size.height*0.5606061);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6566993,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.6648693,size.height*0.5648990,size.width*0.6709150,size.height*0.5715909);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6844771,size.height*0.5866162,size.width*0.6910131,size.height*0.6037879,size.width*0.6968954,size.height*0.6212121);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7052288,size.height*0.6462121,size.width*0.7102941,size.height*0.6715909,size.width*0.7142157,size.height*0.6972222);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7200980,size.height*0.7352273,size.width*0.7227124,size.height*0.7733586,size.width*0.7248366,size.height*0.8114899);

path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5620915,size.height*0.8372475,size.width*0.5602941,size.height*0.8338384,size.width*0.5599673,size.height*0.8303030);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5596405,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5578431,size.height*0.8270202,size.width*0.5545752,size.height*0.8270202);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5460784,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5377451,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5292484,size.height*0.8271465);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5276144,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5259804,size.height*0.8271465,size.width*0.5245098,size.height*0.8268939);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5163399,size.height*0.8252525,size.width*0.5160131,size.height*0.8251263,size.width*0.5147059,size.height*0.8316919);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5114379,size.height*0.8479798,size.width*0.4944444,size.height*0.8568182,size.width*0.4725490,size.height*0.8595960);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4442810,size.height*0.8631313,size.width*0.4156863,size.height*0.8623737,size.width*0.3870915,size.height*0.8607323);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3813725,size.height*0.8603535,size.width*0.3756536,size.height*0.8597222,size.width*0.3699346,size.height*0.8584596);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.3537582,size.height*0.8547980,size.width*0.3470588,size.height*0.8459596,size.width*0.3511438,size.height*0.8343434);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6258170,size.height*0.4420455,size.width*0.6251634,size.height*0.4385101,size.width*0.6210784,size.height*0.4417929);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6168301,size.height*0.4426768,size.width*0.6125817,size.height*0.4435606,size.width*0.6083333,size.height*0.4444444);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6075163,size.height*0.4454545,size.width*0.6060458,size.height*0.4464646,size.width*0.6058824,size.height*0.4474747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6055556,size.height*0.4508838,size.width*0.6042484,size.height*0.4522727,size.width*0.6000000,size.height*0.4502525);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5967320,size.height*0.4494949,size.width*0.5982026,size.height*0.4453283,size.width*0.5931373,size.height*0.4453283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5754902,size.height*0.4452020,size.width*0.5584967,size.height*0.4428030,size.width*0.5418301,size.height*0.4375000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5294118,size.height*0.4335859,size.width*0.5174837,size.height*0.4291667,size.width*0.5058824,size.height*0.4238636);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5029412,size.height*0.4226010,size.width*0.5001634,size.height*0.4210859,size.width*0.4973856,size.height*0.4196970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4913399,size.height*0.4165404,size.width*0.4859477,size.height*0.4125000,size.width*0.4787582,size.height*0.4106061);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4805556,size.height*0.4078283,size.width*0.4846405,size.height*0.4075758,size.width*0.4875817,size.height*0.4063131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4995098,size.height*0.4178030,size.width*0.5339869,size.height*0.4214646,size.width*0.5500000,size.height*0.4135101);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5580065,size.height*0.4094697,size.width*0.5637255,size.height*0.4003788,size.width*0.5560458,size.height*0.3925505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5537582,size.height*0.3902778,size.width*0.5508170,size.height*0.3883838,size.width*0.5488562,size.height*0.3853535);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5503268,size.height*0.3852273,size.width*0.5511438,size.height*0.3849747,size.width*0.5521242,size.height*0.3849747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5683007,size.height*0.3848485,size.width*0.5843137,size.height*0.3842172,size.width*0.6003268,size.height*0.3813131);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6169935,size.height*0.3782828,size.width*0.6333333,size.height*0.3750000,size.width*0.6477124,size.height*0.3672980);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6532680,size.height*0.3642677,size.width*0.6576797,size.height*0.3604798,size.width*0.6609477,size.height*0.3560606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6650327,size.height*0.3506313,size.width*0.6635621,size.height*0.3434343,size.width*0.6570261,size.height*0.3402778);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6452614,size.height*0.3344697,size.width*0.6316993,size.height*0.3319444,size.width*0.6181373,size.height*0.3339646);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6083333,size.height*0.3353535,size.width*0.5985294,size.height*0.3363636,size.width*0.5887255,size.height*0.3377525);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5885621,size.height*0.3366162,size.width*0.5895425,size.height*0.3359848,size.width*0.5905229,size.height*0.3353535);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5919935,size.height*0.3345960,size.width*0.5933007,size.height*0.3337121,size.width*0.5949346,size.height*0.3330808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6163399,size.height*0.3246212,size.width*0.6362745,size.height*0.3143939,size.width*0.6547386,size.height*0.3023990);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6637255,size.height*0.2965909,size.width*0.6718954,size.height*0.2904040,size.width*0.6774510,size.height*0.2823232);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6833333,size.height*0.2736111,size.width*0.6800654,size.height*0.2698232,size.width*0.6718954,size.height*0.2671717);

path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7246732,size.height*0.2135101,size.width*0.7400327,size.height*0.2083333,size.width*0.7532680,size.height*0.2001263);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7563725,size.height*0.1982323,size.width*0.7609477,size.height*0.1964646,size.width*0.7599673,size.height*0.1925505);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7589869,size.height*0.1886364,size.width*0.7539216,size.height*0.1878788,size.width*0.7498366,size.height*0.1867424);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7486928,size.height*0.1864899,size.width*0.7475490,size.height*0.1862374,size.width*0.7464052,size.height*0.1861111);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7354575,size.height*0.1848485,size.width*0.7246732,size.height*0.1842172,size.width*0.7135621,size.height*0.1849747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6928105,size.height*0.1863636,size.width*0.6723856,size.height*0.1881313,size.width*0.6524510,size.height*0.1934343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6364379,size.height*0.1976010,size.width*0.6204248,size.height*0.2012626,size.width*0.6057190,size.height*0.2075758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6037582,size.height*0.2061869,size.width*0.6032680,size.height*0.2042929,size.width*0.6032680,size.height*0.2022727);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6122549,size.height*0.1993687,size.width*0.6215686,size.height*0.1968434,size.width*0.6303922,size.height*0.1936869);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6433007,size.height*0.1888889,size.width*0.6575163,size.height*0.1877525,size.width*0.6709150,size.height*0.1845960);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6901961,size.height*0.1800505,size.width*0.7098039,size.height*0.1791667,size.width*0.7295752,size.height*0.1789141);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7364379,size.height*0.1787879,size.width*0.7431373,size.height*0.1800505,size.width*0.7498366,size.height*0.1809343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7557190,size.height*0.1816919,size.width*0.7602941,size.height*0.1847222,size.width*0.7640523,size.height*0.1880051);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7673203,size.height*0.1907828,size.width*0.7674837,size.height*0.1943182,size.width*0.7648693,size.height*0.1976010);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7622549,size.height*0.2007576,size.width*0.7593137,size.height*0.2040404,size.width*0.7549020,size.height*0.2060606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7459150,size.height*0.2101010,size.width*0.7374183,size.height*0.2151515,size.width*0.7276144,size.height*0.2180556);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7263072,size.height*0.2184343,size.width*0.7245098,size.height*0.2186869,size.width*0.7251634,size.height*0.2202020);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7258170,size.height*0.2215909,size.width*0.7276144,size.height*0.2208333,size.width*0.7287582,size.height*0.2205808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7455882,size.height*0.2176768,size.width*0.7627451,size.height*0.2156566,size.width*0.7799020,size.height*0.2156566);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7947712,size.height*0.2155303,size.width*0.8096405,size.height*0.2161616,size.width*0.8236928,size.height*0.2203283);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8387255,size.height*0.2248737,size.width*0.8434641,size.height*0.2315657,size.width*0.8406863,size.height*0.2440657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8406863,size.height*0.2443182,size.width*0.8408497,size.height*0.2446970,size.width*0.8408497,size.height*0.2449495);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8385621,size.height*0.2455808,size.width*0.8377451,size.height*0.2470960,size.width*0.8374183,size.height*0.2487374);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8297386,size.height*0.2550505,size.width*0.8214052,size.height*0.2604798,size.width*0.8112745,size.height*0.2643939);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8076797,size.height*0.2657828,size.width*0.8034314,size.height*0.2665404,size.width*0.8001634,size.height*0.2683081);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7888889,size.height*0.2744949,size.width*0.7750000,size.height*0.2760101,size.width*0.7629085,size.height*0.2805556);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7580065,size.height*0.2824495,size.width*0.7526144,size.height*0.2835859,size.width*0.7475490,size.height*0.2849747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7620915,size.height*0.2872475,size.width*0.7767974,size.height*0.2839646,size.width*0.7906863,size.height*0.2888889);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7954248,size.height*0.2905303,size.width*0.8011438,size.height*0.2902778,size.width*0.8062092,size.height*0.2912879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8155229,size.height*0.2931818,size.width*0.8246732,size.height*0.2958333,size.width*0.8333333,size.height*0.2992424);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8418301,size.height*0.3025253,size.width*0.8501634,size.height*0.3060606,size.width*0.8560458,size.height*0.3118687);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8627451,size.height*0.3184343,size.width*0.8647059,size.height*0.3267677,size.width*0.8517974,size.height*0.3323232);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8408497,size.height*0.3369949,size.width*0.8292484,size.height*0.3391414,size.width*0.8169935,size.height*0.3401515);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8050654,size.height*0.3411616,size.width*0.7933007,size.height*0.3397727,size.width*0.7812092,size.height*0.3416667);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7689542,size.height*0.3435606,size.width*0.7560458,size.height*0.3421717,size.width*0.7433007,size.height*0.3441919);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7300654,size.height*0.3462121,size.width*0.7165033,size.height*0.3467172,size.width*0.7035948,size.height*0.3503788);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7024510,size.height*0.3507576,size.width*0.7001634,size.height*0.3501263,size.width*0.7003268,size.height*0.3516414);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7004902,size.height*0.3534091,size.width*0.7027778,size.height*0.3534091,size.width*0.7045752,size.height*0.3532828);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7066993,size.height*0.3563131,size.width*0.7114379,size.height*0.3549242,size.width*0.7138889,size.height*0.3569444);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.6977124,size.height*0.3010101);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7045752,size.height*0.2939394,size.width*0.7142157,size.height*0.2902778,size.width*0.7232026,size.height*0.2863636);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7320261,size.height*0.2825758,size.width*0.7421569,size.height*0.2806818,size.width*0.7516340,size.height*0.2775253);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7640523,size.height*0.2733586,size.width*0.7772876,size.height*0.2708333,size.width*0.7898693,size.height*0.2665404);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8013072,size.height*0.2625000,size.width*0.8119281,size.height*0.2578283,size.width*0.8223856,size.height*0.2525253);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8269608,size.height*0.2502525,size.width*0.8303922,size.height*0.2468434,size.width*0.8333333,size.height*0.2434343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8380719,size.height*0.2381313,size.width*0.8361111,size.height*0.2314394,size.width*0.8289216,size.height*0.2281566);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8194444,size.height*0.2238636,size.width*0.8088235,size.height*0.2222222,size.width*0.7982026,size.height*0.2208333);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7794118,size.height*0.2183081,size.width*0.7607843,size.height*0.2213384,size.width*0.7423203,size.height*0.2239899);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7192810,size.height*0.2272727,size.width*0.6978758,size.height*0.2335859,size.width*0.6771242,size.height*0.2419192);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6656863,size.height*0.2464646,size.width*0.6550654,size.height*0.2518939,size.width*0.6441176,size.height*0.2571970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6413399,size.height*0.2584596,size.width*0.6395425,size.height*0.2604798,size.width*0.6369281,size.height*0.2622475);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6390523,size.height*0.2631313,size.width*0.6405229,size.height*0.2627525,size.width*0.6419935,size.height*0.2625000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6498366,size.height*0.2609848,size.width*0.6578431,size.height*0.2607323,size.width*0.6660131,size.height*0.2611111);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6805556,size.height*0.2618687,size.width*0.6887255,size.height*0.2689394,size.width*0.6862745,size.height*0.2789141);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6851307,size.height*0.2834596,size.width*0.6816993,size.height*0.2875000,size.width*0.6782680,size.height*0.2912879);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6656863,size.height*0.3044192,size.width*0.6490196,size.height*0.3140152,size.width*0.6313725,size.height*0.3227273);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6279412,size.height*0.3243687,size.width*0.6253268,size.height*0.3263889,size.width*0.6212418,size.height*0.3289141);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6295752,size.height*0.3292929,size.width*0.6369281,size.height*0.3290404,size.width*0.6442810,size.height*0.3301768);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6598039,size.height*0.3325758,size.width*0.6715686,size.height*0.3412879,size.width*0.6696078,size.height*0.3521465);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6684641,size.height*0.3582071,size.width*0.6643791,size.height*0.3630051,size.width*0.6593137,size.height*0.3670455);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6478758,size.height*0.3758838,size.width*0.6331699,size.height*0.3806818,size.width*0.6181373,size.height*0.3842172);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6022876,size.height*0.3880051,size.width*0.5859477,size.height*0.3895202,size.width*0.5694444,size.height*0.3898990);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5648693,size.height*0.3900253,size.width*0.5622549,size.height*0.3904040,size.width*0.5650327,size.height*0.3946970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5679739,size.height*0.3992424,size.width*0.5673203,size.height*0.4040404,size.width*0.5645425,size.height*0.4087121);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5593137,size.height*0.4172980,size.width*0.5498366,size.height*0.4215909,size.width*0.5385621,size.height*0.4234848);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5336601,size.height*0.4243687,size.width*0.5285948,size.height*0.4243687,size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.4248737);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5413399,size.height*0.4340909,size.width*0.5617647,size.height*0.4373737,size.width*0.5820261,size.height*0.4402778);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5923203,size.height*0.4417929,size.width*0.6029412,size.height*0.4409091,size.width*0.6133987,size.height*0.4382576);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6297386,size.height*0.4339646,size.width*0.6348039,size.height*0.4250000,size.width*0.6264706,size.height*0.4133838);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6217320,size.height*0.4066919,size.width*0.6153595,size.height*0.4008838,size.width*0.6081699,size.height*0.3958333);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6065359,size.height*0.3946970,size.width*0.6040850,size.height*0.3938131,size.width*0.6042484,size.height*0.3916667);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6066993,size.height*0.3906566,size.width*0.6075163,size.height*0.3926768,size.width*0.6093137,size.height*0.3929293);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6274510,size.height*0.3953283,size.width*0.6454248,size.height*0.3983586,size.width*0.6629085,size.height*0.4031566);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6728758,size.height*0.4059343,size.width*0.6834967,size.height*0.4071970,size.width*0.6936275,size.height*0.4099747);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7142157,size.height*0.4155303,size.width*0.7351307,size.height*0.4179293,size.width*0.7566993,size.height*0.4161616);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7638889,size.height*0.4155303,size.width*0.7712418,size.height*0.4141414,size.width*0.7732026,size.height*0.4073232);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7745098,size.height*0.4029040,size.width*0.7722222,size.height*0.3991162,size.width*0.7696078,size.height*0.3954545);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7619281,size.height*0.3845960,size.width*0.7495098,size.height*0.3773990,size.width*0.7364379,size.height*0.3713384);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7210784,size.height*0.3641414,size.width*0.7044118,size.height*0.3584596,size.width*0.6864379,size.height*0.3560606);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.6830065,size.height*0.3555556,size.width*0.6802288,size.height*0.3546717,size.width*0.6774510,size.height*0.3526515);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7006536,size.height*0.3452020,size.width*0.7240196,size.height*0.3396465,size.width*0.7488562,size.height*0.3380051);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7727124,size.height*0.3363636,size.width*0.7968954,size.height*0.3383838,size.width*0.8205882,size.height*0.3345960);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8303922,size.height*0.3329545,size.width*0.8405229,size.height*0.3324495,size.width*0.8495098,size.height*0.3286616);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8540850,size.height*0.3267677,size.width*0.8560458,size.height*0.3237374,size.width*0.8544118,size.height*0.3202020);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8532680,size.height*0.3176768,size.width*0.8513072,size.height*0.3154040,size.width*0.8483660,size.height*0.3135101);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.8344771,size.height*0.3041667,size.width*0.8173203,size.height*0.3001263,size.width*0.8001634,size.height*0.2964646);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7808824,size.height*0.2924242,size.width*0.7609477,size.height*0.2914141,size.width*0.7410131,size.height*0.2934343);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7312092,size.height*0.2944444,size.width*0.7212418,size.height*0.2952020,size.width*0.7120915,size.height*0.2989899);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.7076797,size.height*0.2998737,size.width*0.7031046,size.height*0.3012626,size.width*0.6977124,size.height*0.3010101);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.5959150,size.height*0.6977273);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5967320,size.height*0.6873737,size.width*0.5952614,size.height*0.6747475,size.width*0.5929739,size.height*0.6623737);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5885621,size.height*0.6376263,size.width*0.5812092,size.height*0.6133838,size.width*0.5705882,size.height*0.5897727);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5645425,size.height*0.5762626,size.width*0.5568627,size.height*0.5632576,size.width*0.5503268,size.height*0.5500000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5486928,size.height*0.5468434,size.width*0.5465686,size.height*0.5462121,size.width*0.5426471,size.height*0.5483586);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5351307,size.height*0.5523990,size.width*0.5271242,size.height*0.5560606,size.width*0.5179739,size.height*0.5575758);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5133987,size.height*0.5583333,size.width*0.5135621,size.height*0.5601010,size.width*0.5148693,size.height*0.5625000);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5223856,size.height*0.5762626,size.width*0.5284314,size.height*0.5902778,size.width*0.5334967,size.height*0.6046717);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5410131,size.height*0.6262626,size.width*0.5454248,size.height*0.6483586,size.width*0.5465686,size.height*0.6705808);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5473856,size.height*0.6875000,size.width*0.5462418,size.height*0.7042929,size.width*0.5433007,size.height*0.7212121);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5397059,size.height*0.7420455,size.width*0.5333333,size.height*0.7622475,size.width*0.5248366,size.height*0.7821970);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5232026,size.height*0.7858586,size.width*0.5207516,size.height*0.7893939,size.width*0.5204248,size.height*0.7933081);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5197712,size.height*0.8011364,size.width*0.5191176,size.height*0.8090909,size.width*0.5178105,size.height*0.8169192);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5174837,size.height*0.8193182,size.width*0.5186275,size.height*0.8204545,size.width*0.5220588,size.height*0.8208333);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5344771,size.height*0.8220960,size.width*0.5468954,size.height*0.8217172,size.width*0.5593137,size.height*0.8208333);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5620915,size.height*0.8207071,size.width*0.5632353,size.height*0.8194444,size.width*0.5640523,size.height*0.8178030);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5707516,size.height*0.8046717,size.width*0.5772876,size.height*0.7916667,size.width*0.5821895,size.height*0.7780303);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5913399,size.height*0.7523990,size.width*0.5960784,size.height*0.7265152,size.width*0.5959150,size.height*0.6977273);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7681818);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5240196,size.height*0.7665404,size.width*0.5251634,size.height*0.7654040,size.width*0.5256536,size.height*0.7641414);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5334967,size.height*0.7411616,size.width*0.5388889,size.height*0.7178030,size.width*0.5401961,size.height*0.6940657);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5416667,size.height*0.6688131,size.width*0.5383987,size.height*0.6439394,size.width*0.5312092,size.height*0.6191919);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5254902,size.height*0.5994949,size.width*0.5179739,size.height*0.5803030,size.width*0.5071895,size.height*0.5619949);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5063725,size.height*0.5606061,size.width*0.5060458,size.height*0.5594697,size.width*0.5035948,size.height*0.5597222);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4995098,size.height*0.5601010,size.width*0.4954248,size.height*0.5603535,size.width*0.4915033,size.height*0.5617424);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4885621,size.height*0.5627525,size.width*0.4882353,size.height*0.5637626,size.width*0.4893791,size.height*0.5659091);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.4936275,size.height*0.5746212,size.width*0.4968954,size.height*0.5835859,size.width*0.5001634,size.height*0.5924242);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5124183,size.height*0.6253788,size.width*0.5179739,size.height*0.6592172,size.width*0.5209150,size.height*0.6933081);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7170455,size.width*0.5236928,size.height*0.7407828,size.width*0.5215686,size.height*0.7645202);
    path_1.cubicTo(size.width*0.5214052,size.height*0.7656566,size.width*0.5214052,size.height*0.7669192,size.width*0.5230392,size.height*0.7681818);
    path_1.close();
    path_1.moveTo(size.width*0.6352941,size.height*0.2631313);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6351307,size.height*0.2632576);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6354575,size.height*0.2632576);
    path_1.lineTo(size.width*0.6352941,size.height*0.2631313);
    path_1.close();

    Paint paint_1_fill = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_1_fill.color = color;
    canvas.drawPath(path_1,paint_1_fill);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

everything is good, I send the color and it draws well,

```
return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        CustomPaint(
            painter: PathUno(Color(0xff000000)),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 400)),
        CustomPaint(
            painter: PathDos(Color(0xffffffff)),
            child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: 400)),
      ],
    );
```

but I need to know how can I set a GestureDetector in the right way, because when I put it, any part of the screen gave me that ontap, the idea is: when the user touch that class or path change color,

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should fix your `shouldRepaint` method to only return true when something has changed. Otherwise Flutter will end up repainting when it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the gesture to only react to gestures on the filled part of the custom paint, you need to override `hitTest` on your `CustomPainter` classes:

```
Path? _path;

@override
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
  Path path_1 = Path();
  //...
  _path = path_1;
}

@override
bool? hitTest(Offset offset) {
  return _path?.contains(offset) ?? false;
}
```

[Here's a dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4229fb3d1d93923daf294d884a273c5a) showing it in action. Also see [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57100266/how-do-i-get-to-tap-on-a-custompaint-path-in-flutter-using-gesturedetect) on the same question.